# Enabling Client-Based Culture in Asp.Net Core

Tags: asp.net-mvc, localization, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

In MVC 6 by default, `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` is the one used by windows, not by the browser.

In MVC 5 I could put this in `web.config`:

```
<globalization culture="auto" uiCulture="auto"/>
```

and that would make the `CultureInfo.CurrentCulture` be the same as specified by the browser (`Accept-Language` header).

Is there a way to configure the MVC 6 app to use the browser culture by default?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to install the [Microsoft.AspNet.Localization](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Microsoft.AspNet.Localization/) NuGet package and add the following to your `Startup.cs`:

```
public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app)
{
    app.UseRequestLocalization();
    app.UseMvc();
}
```

By default, it registers the `AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider` as a culture-provider, that should be equivalent to the legacy `enableClientBasedCulture` setting.

**Update:**

As per your comment, since you're using the RC1 version, you must provide a default culture to the method. For example:

```
app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestCulture("en"));
```

Comment: for me (mvc 6 rc1-final) this extension is available without installing the localization package ( I tried installing, makes no difference ); also the extension requires at least 1 parameter so I tried `app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestCulture("en"));` it only works if you put it before `app.UseMvc` and it ignores the browser language

Comment: that also requires specifying RequestCulture (so 2 parameters), and the result is the same

Comment: Can you check which is the assembly that provides your `UseRequestLocalization()` extension method?

Comment: namespace Microsoft.AspNet.Builder Microsoft.AspNet.Localization.dll

Comment: How are you actually checking the current culture?

Comment: (it looks like localization is a dependency now on Microsoft.AspNet.Mvc;)
I check it by having this in the view: `@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name @CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.DateTimeFormat.ShortDatePattern`

Comment: What is your actual `Accept-Language` in the request, and what does `@CultureInfo.CurrentCulture.Name` outputs?

Comment: `Accept-Language:de-DE,de;q=0.8,en-US;q=0.6,en;q=0.4` and it's outputting `en` and `M/d/yyyy`

Comment: @Omu, I believe the problem is that you need to add `de-DE` to the `SupportedCultures` list in `RequestLocalizationOptions`. Something like: `app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestCulture("en"), new RequestLocalizationOptions { SupportedCultures = new List<CultureInfo> { new CultureInfo("de-DE") } });`

Comment: adding SupportedCultures worked, but that means that I need to add all the possible cultures to that list

Comment: @Omu, Apparently. And this line is the culprit: https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/blob/b52e33caa7927093dc3ec540fd3282f4f69ae169/src/Microsoft.Extensions.Globalization.CultureInfoCache/CultureInfoCache.cs#L34

Comment: @Omu, I added an issue on GitHub: https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/issues/237

Comment: A small correction, it doesn't register to `AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider` only. All 3 providers are registered (QueryStringRequestCultureProvider, CookieRequestCultureProvider and AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider) in exact this order. The order is important because it decides which will take precedence. If you provide a query parameter, this one will be taken and cookie and accept header will be ignored even if set. If no query was provided it will check if there is a cookie and use that instead. Only then it uses accept-language header if provided

Comment: You can also see that in the code on GitHub: https://github.com/aspnet/Localization/blob/1.0.0-rc1/src/Microsoft.AspNet.Localization/RequestLocalizationOptions.cs

Comment: @Tseng, I never meant that `AcceptLanguageHeaderRequestCultureProvider` is the only provider used. I only mentioned it because it's the one that is relevant to the question.

Comment: Yes, but for other users and users new to ASP.NET Core who come and find this question it may not be obvious that there are other types of providers and that they take precedence and may be surprised, so it would be good to mention it in the answer for the future readers